# On codepen, do the pens have to be used as is or can one modify them and use them?

Tags: codepen

Yes that's my question, I just wanted to know because if I want to modify the pen and it's illegal to do it I don't want to do it obviously.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This isn't really a programming question, more of a tech support question for Codepen. But yeah, you can fork the pen and modify it all you want.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a tech support question for a website that happens to be related to programming.

Comment: You have answered my question thanks, how do I choose that your comment was the answer to my question? It doesn't give me the option